# C++ No instance of constructor "Card::Card" matches the argument list

Tags: c++, class, constructor

**This is my Card struct header file:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
enum Suits {clubs, diamonds, hearts, spades};
enum Ranks {two = 2, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten, jack, queen, king, ace};

struct Card {   
    Card (Suits suit, Ranks rank);
private:
    Suits suit_;
    Ranks rank_;
};
```

**I initialize the Card member variables in my cpp:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"    
#include "Card.h"
#include "Header.h"

using namespace std;

Card::Card (Suits suit, Ranks rank) : suit_(suit), rank_(rank) {}
```

**Now, I am trying to parse a bunch of card definition string, such as 2C, 3h, 7s, 10h in a function**

```
int FileParsing(vector<Card> & v, char * FileName) {
    ... //omiting the details, basically open FileName, parse card definition strings
    //After I finish parsing 10h, I tried to push it back
    v.push_back(Card(ten, hearts)); //got an error here
    ... 
    return 0;
}
```

**My suspection is the type conflicts in Card(Suits, ranks), but I am not sure. Any input will be greatly appreciated!!!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
v.push_back(Card(ten, hearts)); //got an error here
```

must this not be

```
v.push_back(Card(hearts, ten));
```

?

Comment: Thank you very much, got confused with myself after writing some parsing code.

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor takes suit then rank.

```
Card::Card (Suits suit, Ranks rank) : suit_(suit), rank_(rank) {}
```

Your parameters are backwards when you create it here.

```
v.push_back(Card(hearts, ten));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, got confused with myself after writing some parsing code.

Answer (score 1):

```
v.push_back(Card(ten, hearts)); //got an error here
```

should be written as:

```
v.push_back(Card(hearts, ten)); //fixed
```

Because the first argument to `Card` should be `Suits`, and second should be `Ranks`.

Comment: Thank you very much, got confused with myself after writing some parsing code.

Answer (score 1):

If `ten` and `hearts` are of type `Suits` and `Ranks` accordingly, then it looks like you just have your constructor arguments in the wrong order.  The constructor is `Card(Suits, Ranks)`, but you are trying to call `Card(Ranks,Suits)`.  Switch around your constructor arguments and it should work.